# SonarQube - sonar.projectBaseDir Network Location? Subversion Trunk?

Tags: svn, sonarqube

Hello Dear SonarQube Enthusiasts,

I was wondering if it was possible to specify a network location for the element in a `sonar-runner` properties file, `sonar.projectBaseDir`. I was trying to do this: `sonar.projectBaseDir = https://subversion-server/svn/Project/trunk` This however gave an `EXECUTION FAILURE` because `sonar-runner` simply appended the network location specified to the current directory and looked there instead of across the Intranet.

Does anyone know how to specify a network location as a scan directory; so I am constantly scanning the updated code from a network location?

Thank-you for reading this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sonar.projectBaseDir` needs to be reachable using a file protocol, so specifying a web address will not work.

OTOH, you appear to be trying to reference a project stored in Subversion, so why not simply check the project out into your current directory and go from there?

In the long run, it will make your life much simpler because referencing the svn directory across the network would require hacks that will be difficult to maintain long-term.

Comment: Thanks again for the help Ann. :) I was hoping to not have to check out the code into a directory and save a step.